# How to create a duplicate Xcode project (without ads)

Tags: iphone, xcode, mercurial, project, duplicates

I know this has been asked, but all of the threads I find do not answer my specific question.

I have an app that is free, and contains ads.  I would like to make a duplicate of this app without ads to offer for a price.

I have read about duplicating the target in my project, but I don't understand how this would work seeing as I would need different versions of the same nib files.

I have also read about duplicating my complete project folder... but I am using Mercurial, and am bumping into source control/repository issues when trying to do this.

I am a bit lost.. can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two targets: one for AD-aware version, other for paid version. Then, you can use conditional compilation (one Storyboard/NIB for each version, "#if"s, etc).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't understand how to have it use different nib's though..?

Comment: Each target you configure the "Main Window" property (or "Main Storyboard") by editing the Info.plist or clicking on Project in "Project Navigator".